# The Method to append results of a "for loop"  in a variable while it is running?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, append

While a "for loop" is running in VB.net, C# or Python which method can be used to append each result to a variable?

Comment: please give us a better explanation of the problem and the code you have so far.

Comment: Hi Zach, sorry this was a complete beginners question (with no code) but Justin and Abbas' replies below really helped me! I have made the question a bit more clear I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? This will store each item (`singleCharacter`) in the iteration, thereby keeping them in memory.

```
Dim someString As String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
Dim vals As List(Of Char) = New List(Of Char)

For Each singleCharacter As Char In someString
    vals.Add(singleCharacter)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a For Each loop, with a For loop it would look like this:

```
Dim someString As String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
Dim vals As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

For i As Integer = 0 To someString.Length - 1 Step 1
    vals.Add(someString(i))
Next
```

Comment: Hi Abbas, I am not sure why you got -1, your reply was very helpful, I am voting you up.